# crystal report (No source availabe)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have made a Windows application using C# and crystal report and this is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
        string connStr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Reg;Integrated Security=TRUE";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string query1 = "Select name,phone,mobile from Register";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, connStr);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "my_dt");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("mafeesh");
            return;
        }

        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
    }
```

When I run the program the following error occurs:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP
>   BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP
>   BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Do you know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your app.config file

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
 </startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the dll files from Bin folder,and then build again your solution....i hope so far that this will help you